# Search user with clickable result and when clicked, it will go directly to it's profile

Tags: php, mysql

I've create a search.php and it is already connected on database. I want the result to be clickable. for example, when you search a name on facebook, the result is clickable and then when you click it, it will directly go to user's profile. what code will i add? Here is my code:

```
  $sql="SELECT schoId, schoSurname, schoFirstname FROM tblscholar WHERE schoSurname LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR schoFirstname LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $schoSurname=$row['schoSurname'];
  $schoFirstname=$row['schoFirstname'];
  $schoId=$row['schoId'];
  echo $row["schoSurname"];
  echo $row["schoFirstname"];
```

Comment: with "clickable result" you mean something like a link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another page in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-page-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do really depends on how your user profile link looks like, but it should be something like this

```
echo '<a href="http://www.yourdomain.com/user/'.$schoId.'">'.$schoFirstname.' '.$schoSurname.'</a>';
```

which would output

[Name Surname](http://www.yourdomain.com/user/1)

Of course you don't need an absolute URL if you're within the same domain, but I hope it's easier to understand like this.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so it means that every user must have their own .php?

Comment: @cutiepatootie Generally speaking you have one template user page which loads the user data based on the user id from the URL. So you don't have to create hundreds upon hundreds of user files, but you do need to know how to output all data correctly.

Comment: @cutiepatootie If this was the right answer please do not forget to mark is as such :)